# Verify array with post value php

Tags: php, arrays, post, crm

I  have a question about sending data with POST in a form to crm

this is my html code:

```
 <select name="niveau" class="validate[required] interesse  custom-select" type="text" id="niveau">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Niveau d'études</option>
        <option value="1">Tronc commun ou Seconde</option>
        <option value="2">1ere année bac ou Première</option>
        <option value="3">2eme année bac ou Terminale</option>
        <option value="4">Déjà bachelier</option>
        <option value="5">Bac +1</option>
        <option value="6">Bac +2</option>
        <option value="7">Bac +3</option>
        <option value="8">Bac +4</option>
        <option value="9">Bac +5</option>
      </select>
```

i get the value with jquery and send it to database it works fine
but when i want verify for 
ex: in input we have value "7" i want that field in crm "new_niveaudetudessuperieures" get "100 000 002"

```
$nn=array(
1=> "100 000 000",
2=> "100 000 001",
3=> "100 000 002" ,
4=> "100 000 006",
5=> "100 000 006",
6=> "100 000 001",
7=> "100 000 002" ,
8=> "100 000 003" ,
9=> "100 000 004" ,
 );
if( $_POST['niveau'] >= 4)
 {

 $contact->new_niveaubacalaureat = $nn[$_POST['niveau']];

 }

  else{
 $contact->new_niveaudetudessuperieures = $nn[$_POST['niveau']];
}
```

i want to verify the value and then add it to the crm but i just get empty value

Comment: Where's your php?

Comment: i just put it now

Comment: Which value is empty? Maybe you should add some debug output to show if your code is actually run and what intermediate values you get.

Comment: @Bodo "niveau" field

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information. If you mean that `$_POST['niveau']` is empty, write this in your question and show minimal complete working form code.

Comment: i ve edited the question

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` share the result

Comment: it show " Array "

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 
`<form action="" method="POST><select.../></form>` 
structure, Could you please give us more details about your issue.

Thank you

Comment: <form id="formul" action="/api.php" >
jquery code

    $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
      dataType : "json",
      url  : form.attr('action'),
      data : form.serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        if (data.response=="Le contact est bien cree!") 
        {
 
         window.location.href= '/uic/success.html';
        }
        else
          {
          alert('Email Existe Deja!!');
        }

Comment: This should be a comment as it is not an answer.

Comment: You have to use method="post" in your form

Comment: yes i don't have problem with that because i m using  type : 'post' with ajax